# How's the performance differences between SSJS and AMPScript in Automation Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, automationstudio

I'm planning to process >100K records in a DE table using automation studio. I can write the correct logic using SSJS. However, I found out the performance of SSJS is really poor and always get timeout error.

How about if I rewrite the SSJS with AMPScript? Will it improve the speed of the script? Is there any performance differences between them? If not, I'll think the solution besides Script activities.

Comment: Maybe you should reprogramm your logic or share it within this community, i believe we cannot help without more information

Comment: What do you mean by "process" >100k records?  Delete them?  Update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AMPscript in a Script Activity directly.  A timeout on processing 100k DE rows doesn't surprise me.  Script Activities aren't meant to replace Query Activities, nor do they work well for batch data operations.

Two ways I've approached this before:

- Add a mechanism to your process that keeps track of the DE rows that have been processed and then duplicate your script activity multiple times in your Automation.
- Build two unscheduled Automations and write a Script Activity that starts the other.  This allows you to run Automations more frequently than once an hour.

Without more details of your process, it's hard to say which approach I'd take.